# How do you mount a k8s service account token as an enviromnet variable?

Tags: kubernetes

When you associate a service account to a pod, it gets mounted in the `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/` folder, but I don't see a way to add the secret as an environment variable.  The issue is that setting up a reference in the pod to a service account's secret is not possible because the secret generated from service account has an auto generated name.  So you can't use `env.valueFrom.secretKeyRef` in the pod config.  Is there a way to do this without creating a secret manually?

Comment: What Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @mozello 1.23.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a native Kubernetes way to solve this problem, but I solved it with terraform.  The service_account resource provides the [default_secret_name](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/service_account_v1#default_secret_name) which allows me to reference the secret in the deployment (or pod).

```
resource "kubernetes_service_account_v1" "my_service_account" {
  metadata {
    name      = "my-service-account"
  }
}

...

resource "kubernetes_deployment_v1" "my_deployment" {
  ...
  env {
    name = "SOME_SECRET"
    value_from {
      secret_key_ref {
        name = kubernetes_service_account_v1.my_service_account.default_secret_name
        key  = "token"
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```